# how to make section as only in run time

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, linker

while creating an image from elf I saw that I can make the image smaller by not loading some section to the image (such that hold uninitialized variables for example).
I need to change the way a specific section in memory is allocated.
I want a specific section to be used only in run time, and that it will not take place in the image itself.

working with GCC version 10 and ARM processor.

is there a way to do so with an "attribute" or section header?

thanks

Comment: What ARM, more specifically? If this is a microcontroller system then your requirement doesn't make much sense - you have as much memory as is available on the chip, period.

Comment: GCC should already be doing the best it can do in this regard.  If you have file-scope or and / or static variables that are explicitly or by default initialized to 0, then you should expect GCC to assign them to the .bss segment, which occupies almost no space in the binary.  Automatic and dynamically-allocated variables will not occupy space in the binary, either.  Everything else that exists at runtime needs to be represented in the binary or in external dynamically linked libraries.

Comment: If you want to more generally reduce the size of the binary, however, then you should consider optimizing for size (`-Os`) instead of for speed (`-O` and most `-Ox` options).

Comment: arm cortex m4, is it relevant? I thought it is a compiler/linker change.
I want to make the binary a small as I can since the flash size is not big in my case.

are you saying that the GCC already makes those variables (initialised and not0 to the bss?